# How to show "About" text from JSON file in HTML on clicking in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I have added images to my project through a JSON file, which is working quite well. But now I am struggling to make the "About" show too. What would be the simplest way to show the about in a discrete div that opens and closes with the "ABOUT" of each project on click?

More details:
I am currently building a project which includes a lot of images so it was suggested I use a JSON file which works great, but my initial version had everything in HTML, but I had an Image slider issue which solved my issue with the images. So the javascript will get all the image information and alt text from the JSON file.

Now my issue here is since I added this JSON method now I don't know how to add my description side panel which describes the project, with the project TITLE and an ABOUT section.

So I can send you an example of one of my websites where I am doing exactly what I would like to replicate when I click on project N°1 for example: https://www.annihilate-the-caste-system.com/

So for the HTML I would like to add but it's not working :

```
    <div id="open-right-panel-1" class="about-title cursor-pointer" style="z-index: 10000000;">
            <div id="pantonier-1">
              
              <div class="descriptionSide">
                <div class="title" style="color: white;">Description</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="description hidden-about">
              <u>Project Name</u><br>
              <div style="margin-left: 7%;">
                <p>Project description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The HTML part where images from each project are being shown and then the Nav section is automatically populated by the JSON content, and once you click on a certain image you enter the content of that project.

```
    <nav class="nav-wrapper row horizontalList">
      <!-- PROJECT LIST FROM JSON DATA -->
      <ul id="project-list" class="cursor-pointer"></ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery-wrapper slideshow-container">
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p1_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
          <!-- DESCRIPTION PANEL -->
          <!-- <div id="open-right-panel-1" class="about-title cursor-pointer" style="z-index: 10000000;">
            <div id="pantonier-1">
              
              <div class="descriptionSide">
                <div class="title" style="color: white;">Description</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="description hidden-about">
              <u>Project Name</u><br>
              <div style="margin-left: 7%;">
                <p>Project description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p2_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
          
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p3_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p4_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p5_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden buttonLeft" aria-label="Previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
      <div class="hidden buttonLeft" aria-label="Next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
    </section>
```

The JS looks like this to fill up the HTML, using anchors

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 populateMenuList();
 setProject(data.Projects[0])
 $(".about-title").on("click", () => toggleAboutOverlay())
});

function populateMenuList() {
   data.Projects.forEach(i => {
       var listElement = $(`<li class="list-item">${i.Title}</li>`)
       listElement.on("click", () => {setProject(i)})
       $("#project-list").append(listElement)
   });
}


var isSlicked = false

function setProject(project) {
   // Stop Slick to avoid bugs
   if(isSlicked) {
       $(".gallery-wrapper").slick("unslick")
       $(".gallery-wrapper").empty()
   }
   // Set images in slick gallery (dont forget to add alt text)
   project.Images.forEach(i => { 
       $(".gallery-wrapper").append(`<div><img src="./assets/img/${i.FileName}" alt="${i.AltText}"></div>`)
   })
   // Restart Slick
   isSlicked = true
   $(".gallery-wrapper").slick({
       autoplay: false,
       autoplaySpeed: 2000,
       arrows: true,
       adaptiveHeight: true,
   });
}
```

And finally the JSON file

```
 Projects : [
    {
      "Title": "Project_1",
      "About": "Description",
      "Images": [
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_1.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_2.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_3.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_4.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_5.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet",
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_6.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_7.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p1_img_8.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      
      "Title": "Project_2",
      "About": "My project description",
      "Images": [
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_1.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_2.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_3.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_4.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_5.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_6.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_7.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_8.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_9.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "p2_img_9.jpg",
          "AltText" : "Première image du projet"
        }
      ]
    },
```

So my question is how can I integrate the description panel which slides out from the right side per project?

Thanks in advance!